# Using folderId reference to SPPlaylistFolder

Tags: ios, playlist, spotify

I want to be able to automatically create playlists in an specific playlist folder (also created by my app).

In order to do this,  I'd like to save a reference to a created `SPPlaylistFolder` and be able to access it later (i.e. when adding playlists 2 – n).

Looking at the *CocoaLibSpotify* docs, it seems like using the `folderId` property would be a way of doing it. But the docs also state:

> Important: This should only be used if you plan to directly use the C
>   LibSpotify API. The behaviour of CocoaLibSpotify is undefined if you
>   use the C API directly on items that have CocoaLibSpotify objects
>   associated with them.

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret this... Just looking at the `folderId` property and the methods related to it (e.g. `-playlistFolderForFolderId:inContainer:`), it seems like it's possible to do what I want? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `folderId` property of `SPPlaylistFolder` without problems. However, when the Spotify client renames a folder, the folderId will change.

At the moment there doesn't appear to be a valid way of tracking folders through renames and moves between sessions. We're actively working on this, but in the meantime you'll have to use a best-attempt against folderId and name.